# Sending Push Notifications to every user in Android

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which user can post a certain request with his details using the application. And that request should be sent to **every** user who has installed the application. I would like an insight on this topic.. Also what kind of android service I have to use to achieve this?
Will I need a **broadcastReceiver** or a **localBroadcastReceiver** to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean [`LocalBroadcastManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)? That's normally for internal events. Go for `BroadcastReceiver`.

Anyway, I would also recommend [Sinch](https://www.sinch.com) (I'm using it right now alongside Parse), [Pubnub](https://www.pubnub.com), [Pusher](https://www.pusher.com). See which one works best for you. They all have their limitations, they work well in some areas and bad in others. If you could give more details about what you need, it would be great.

Answer (score 2):

`Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)` for **Android** is a service that allows you to send data from your server to your users' Android-powered device, and also to receive messages from devices on the same connection. The `GCM` service handles all aspects of queuing of messages and delivery to the target Android application running on the target device, and it is completely free.

Go to [Official Docs](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html)

Another Example http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: Can I integrate it with Parse.com as I am hosting my database on it instead of using php as server side scripting?

Answer (score 0):

If you using php web services, then its a work of php server side. Php web services receive your request to send push notification to all users. And services fetch all users device id and send notification to all users.